# annotation that changes the string value

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Is there an annotation in spring or java that transforms a given string?

For example, Spring has the annotation @Value("some string"). What if instead of assigning "some string" to the parameter/instance variable whatever, I want to assign a transformed value of that string. Let's say the string is "foo". Every time I see this annotation I want the string returned to be "bar:foo" and not foo. All I want is to be able to place an annotation over a parameter or instance variable and for that transformation to occur automatically. Perhaps maybe even an annotation that takes a class as well as the string such that the class acts as the transformer for the given string.

Is there an annotation in spring or java that does this and if not what would be the best way to go about implementing such a thing?

Thanks
Lauren

Comment: I don't get this question... maybe you can provide some pseudo code outlining your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Expression Language inside your `@Value` annotation.

This is how you'll use it for a static method:

```
@Value("#{T(fully.qualified.package.name.to.class).getFooString()}")
public void setBar(String value){
   this.bar = value;
}
```

If you have a bean define previously then you can simply use
`@Value("#{bean.method()}")` or `@Value("#{bean.property}")`

Answer (score 0):

The `@Value` annotation of Spring is useful to assign a value other than a constant to a property, using the Spring expression language. For example, a value read from a properties file. If all it did was assigning a constant, you could as well use `private String foo = "bar";`.

So, you might use it to get the value you want from some configuration file or system property.

If what you want is to apply some transformation algorithm to a field, I don't really see the point of using an annotation. Just call a Java method:

```
@Value("foo") // or some EL expression which evaluates to "foo"
public void setBar(String value) {
    this.bar = someStringTransformer.transform(value);
}
```

That seems easy to read, test and maintain.